# How to use $dateToString in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this aggregate in mongoDB.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
          "$dateToString": {
              "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
              "date": {
                    "$add": [
                      "$timestamp",
                      18000000
                    ]
              }
          }
        },
      "list": {
        "$addToSet": "$timestamp"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But when I use this aggregate with mongoose, it says this error.

```
{
    "ok": 0,
    "errmsg": "unknown group operator '$dateToString'",
    "code": 15952,
    "codeName": "Location15952",
    "name": "MongoError"
}
```

I searched that there isn't $dateToString in mongoose as follow this link.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html
How can I modify my mongoDB agrregate for mongoose? THank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

- the Error does not come from mongoose but from MongoDB itself
- [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) takes the date first, then the format
- `$dateToString` is only available from MongoDB v3.0 (are you running MongoDB >= v3.0?)
- `$dateToString` is not available inside a `$group _id`  operator (also technically it should be, well the error message says it isn't)

Add a `$project` stage before the `$group` stage and add the date conversion there.
Then you can group by your new field you introduced in `$project`.